# Including standalone C code into assembler

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

I haven't looked in ages how the computer actually starts up, so I started playing around with writing my own loader which would boot into IA-32e mode and initialize all the CPUs with some dummy code to run. I'm fairly far, but I'm getting tired of writing trivial things in assembler.

Here's a toy case of what I would like to achieve. Say I want to write a simple piece of code that prints a C-style string and keeps track of the cursor in some fixed location in memory. A C implementation would be something along the following lines (this code is untested, I wrote it on the fly, so don't comment on bugs, since they're not relevant):

```
#define VIDEORAM_ADDRESS        0xa0000
#define VIDEORAM_LINE_LENGTH    160
#define VGA_GREY_ON_BLACK       0x07
#define CURSOR_X                0x100 /* dummy address */
#define CURSOR_Y                0x101

void printk(const char *s)
{
    volatile char *p;
    int x, y;

    x = *(volatile char*)CURSOR_X;
    y = *(volatile char*)CURSOR_Y;

    while(*s != 0) {
        if(*s == '\n') {
            y++;
            y = y >= 25 ? 0 : y;
            x = 0;
        } else {
            x++;
            if(x >= 80) {
                y++;
                y = y >= 25 ? 0 : y;
                x = 0;
           }
           p = (volatile char*)VIDEORAM_ADDRESS + x + y * VIDEORAM_LINE_LENGTH;
           *p++ = *s++;
           *p = VGA_GREY_ON_BLACK;
        }
    }

    *(volatile char*)CURSOR_X = x;
    *(volatile char*)CURSOR_Y = y;
}
```

I can compile this with `gcc -m32 -O2 -S printk.c`, which generates `printk.s`. My question is essentially how to combine this together with a handwritten assembly file? The end result should of course be nothing else except a single binary blob of machine code and data that is loaded by the BIOS onto `0000:7C00` if, say, I want to include the code into the stage 1 loader loaded from a disk and call it after switching over to protected mode.

Is an alternative putting an `.include` directive somewhere in the handwritten assembly file to get the code included? Unfortunately, gcc emits all kinds of directives for the GNU Assembler in the .s file and I really only want the code for the `printk` function.

Is there some canonical way of doing this?

Comment: The way to combine it would be compile the C code to an object file (.o),  assemble the assembly code to an object file and link the two a linker (ie. `ld`). However since GCC is a 32-bit compiler the code it generates won't work in a 16-bit boot sector. If you want to print out something in boot sector I would recommend using the INT 0x10 BIOS services. You don't have a lot of space to available in a boot sector, and writing to video memory directly is going to take a big chunk of it. You also don't have to worry about getting things like address of video memory correct.

Comment: This particular C code was just an example. I just want to be able to write some code in C as early as possible and combine it with assembly. The gcc generated assembly code works fine, once I switch to protected mode, which is something I do in the loader right after using the BIOS to read in the stage 2 loader. The problem with the linker is that it generates an ELF binary, so if I postpone using C to later in the process I would have to write the ELF parser in assembly. My goal is to minimize the assembly code.

Comment: That's not what you said in your question. In any case the linker isn't limited to creating ELF executables, it can create binary files as well.

Comment: Well, I did say that "say, I want to include the code into the stage 1 loader loaded from a disk and call it after switching over to protected mode." Do you happen to know a link to some docs that explain how to let the linker generate binary? The compiler would also need to be instructed to generate relative jumps.

Comment: Documentation for the GNU linker (ld) is easy to find. All near non-indirect jumps are relative in the x86 instruction set and GCC can't generate anything other than near jumps. Don't use function pointers and all you have is relative jumps. If what you really mean is you want position independent code, you don't need that. You can have the linker  fixup everything so that absolute references use the address the code is run at. That would require you to write a suitable linker script.